# Jasmine unit test wait for asynchronous calls

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, asynchronous, jasmine, karma-runner

How do I make Jasmine wait for asynchronous functions to finish before running expect's?

I want to test scope.init() in my controller. This function contains 3 asynchronous calls similar to this one

```
$scope.init = function() {

   //populate parameterList 

    myService.getDropdowns(parameterList).then(function(response) {
        if (response && response.data) {
            $scope.dropdown1 = response.data;
        }

    }, function(errorResponse) {
        $log.error(errorResponse);
    });

  //populate parameterList 

    myService.getDropdowns(parameterList).then(function(response) {
        if (response && response.data) {
            $scope.dropdown2 = response.data;
        }

    }, function(errorResponse) {
        $log.error(errorResponse);
    });

};
```

How can I wait for dropdown1, dropdown2, dropdown3 to be populated before running my expect's? I am trying to test that each dropdown is populated successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
 describe('your test', function(){

    beforeEach(function(done){
        // You can call any async task, when done() is called the test will begin
        setTimeout(() => {done();}, 100); 
    });

    it('Column Definitions created', function(){
        expect($scope.a).toBe(3);
    });
});
```